# How to iterate through IDataReader

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I am using .Net 4.5, C#, Oracle 11g with EF 4.4.0.0

**Existing Process**

So, we have a DataModel which resembles the underlying Database structure and appropriate Entity Objects created as classes in our application. We are not always using EF to load the data as sometimes we use stored procedures to load data to the client and then map the data record by record the Entity classes in our application.

The existing code

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var accounts = new Dictionary<Decimal, ApplicationDomain.MainView.EMPLOYEE_MASTER>();

using (var cmd = new OracleCommand("PKG_TEST.GetAllEmployees", (OracleConnection)Db.Connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DEPT_ID", userBankId));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EMPLOYEE_P", OracleDbType.RefCursor, 0, ParameterDirection.Output, true, 0, 0, string.Empty, DataRowVersion.Default, Convert.DBNull));
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    Db.Open();
    using (IDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        try
        {
            dataTable.Load(dataReader );

            foreach (BusinessObjectBuilder<ApplicationDomain.MainView.EMPLOYEE_MASTER> employeeBuilder in
                dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => new BusinessObjectBuilder<ApplicationDomain.MainView.EMPLOYEE_MASTER>(row)).Where(
                        accountBuilder => ((IBusinessObjectBuilder<ApplicationDomain.MainView.EMPLOYEE_MASTER>)employeeBuilder).Value != null))
            {
                var employee = ((IBusinessObjectBuilder<ApplicationDomain.MainView.EMPLOYEE_MASTER>)employeeBuilder).Value;
                try
                {
                    if (!employees.ContainsValue(employee))
                    {
                        employees.Add(employee.EMPLOYEE_ID, employee);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _log.InfoFormat("Employee ID already exists for this Department : Employee Id{0}", employee.EMPLOYEE_ID);
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dataReader != null && !dataReader.IsClosed)
            {
                dataReader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `BusinessObjectBuilder` class takes each row of `EMPLOYEE` and maps it with the Entity properties as we have defined in the application. Currently this is being done for every row of the data-table, after its been loaded with the data from the IDataReader.

**What I am looking for**

We are looking to get rid of the part where the DataTable is being loaded with data from the reader. I want to directly use the `BusinessObjectBuilder` with rows/records from `dataReader` object and map it to corresponding Entity properties.

As you can see above, the process loops through every single row inside the datatable, successfully maps each record into an Entity object and send it back, which will be added to a `Dictionary`, with the `EMPLOYEE_ID` as the key.

**Problem**

I cannot find a way to iterate through the `dataReader` object, get individual record and then do the process being done through `BusinessObjectBuilder`, add it to the `Dictionary`, with the `EMPLOYEE_ID` as the key.

Is there any way we can iterate through an IDataReader instance, the same way or some other way like we do with a DataTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.dataprocessing.idatareader.read.aspx) method to read the next record, and [`GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.dataprocessing.idatareader.getvalue.aspx) to get the value from a column:

```
while(dataReader.Read()) 
{
  var value1 = reader.GetValue(0); // first column
  var value2 = reader.GetValue(1); // second column
}
```

I would add *overloads* to `BusinessObjectBuilder` to read from an `IDataReader` instead of replacing the `DataTable` methods (in case you need them in the future).

Comment: @D Stanley, I don't want to change the `BusinessObjectBuilder` process. Its accepts only data rows and overloading the process is not possible. I have to pass a record...

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky A data reader does not contain `DataRow` objects - you'll need to load a data table if you want to have data rows.  Pick your poison...